# How to extract fields from JSON using?

Tags: json, jtc

Given the JSON excerpt shown below, I can use `jtc` to extract these fields.  But I can't obtain the "Status: Problem" field below.  Thanks for any help with this.

```
<events.json jtc -w'<title>l' -w'<^environment:>R' -w'<host>l' -w'<date_happened>l' -w'<^name:>R' -w'<Status:>l'
"CPU Utilization Alert is ok on 50 over 50 host,names"
"environment:prod"
"i-0e4b192579a9b423b"
1573502725
"name:app2_backend-prod"
```

```
{
    "events": [
        {
            "alert_type": "success",
            "children": [
                {
                    "alert_type": "error",
                    "date_happened": 1573502725,
                    "id": "5188183926379101887"
                },
                {
                    "alert_type": "success",
                    "date_happened": 1573503145,
                    "id": "5188190972457497744"
                }
            ],
            "comments": [],
            "date_happened": 1573502725,
            "device_name": null,
            "host": "i-0e4b192579a9b423b",
            "id": 5188183933173874377,
            "is_aggregate": true,
            "priority": "normal",
            "resource": "/api/v1/events/5188183933173874377",
            "source": "Monitor Alert",
            "tags": [
                "autoscaling_group:app2_backend-asg-prod",
                "availability-zone:us-east-1b",
                "datadog-agent:true",
                "environment:prod",
                "host:i-0e4b192579a9b423b",
                "iam_profile:app2_backend_instance_profile",
                "image:ami-2769055d",
                "instance-type:m4.large",
                "kernel:none",
                "monitor",
                "name:app2_backend-prod",
                "region:us-east-1",
                "role:app2_backend",
                "security-group:sg-04bacd76",
                "security-group:sg-0a30f49295ece70c9",
                "security-group:sg-0c121cf3defc0b22d",
                "security-group:sg-249eb156",
                "security-group:sg-2f4e4f5c",
                "security-group:sg-af82addd",
                "security-group:sg-b6c7ddc4",
                "security-group:sg-cf85aabd",
                "siteconfig:true"
            ],
            "text": "%%%\nQuery recovered on host:i-0e4b192579a9b423b,name:app2_backend-prod \n\n![snapshot](https://p.datadoghq.com/snapshot/view/dd-snapshots-prod/org_125488/2019-11-11/87f3217c72423a6ba45a1e8e096bb07ff02c08f3.png)\n\n{{#is_alert}}  \nStatus: Problem\nHost:         {{name.name}} \nHost ID:    {{host.name}}\nHost IP:     {{host.ip}}\n{{/is_alert}}\n\n{{#is_warning}}  \nStatus: Problem\nHost:        {{name.name}} \nHost ID:     {{host.name}}\nHost IP:     {{host.ip}}\n{{/is_warning}}\n\n\n{{#is_recovery}} \nStatus: OK\nHost:         {{name.name}} \nHost ID:     {{host.name}}\nHost IP:      {{host.ip}}\n{{/is_recovery}}\n\n @bbarton@signatureinfo.com\n\n- - -\n\n[[Monitor Status](/monitors#2785042?)] \u00b7 [[Edit Monitor](/monitors#2785042/edit)] \u00b7 [[Related Logs](/logs?query=)]\n%%%",
            "title": "CPU Utilization Alert is ok on 50 over 50 host,names",
            "url": "/event/event?id=5188183933173874377"
        },
```

Comment: Could you clarify following: `Status: Problem` occurs twice in the `text` field. Which part would you like to extract from there?

Comment: Oh, where it says "Status: Problem".   -Thanks

Comment: I provided an answer, let me know if that's what you're after

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 encounters of `Status: Problem` in the `text` filed, assuming you would want the text in between you could do it using this regex search:

```
bash $ <events.json jtc -w'[text]:<nStatus: Problem(.*)(?=Status: Problem)>R' -T'{{$1}}'
"\nHost:         {{name.name}} \nHost ID:    {{host.name}}\nHost IP:     {{host.ip}}\n{{/is_alert}}\n\n{{#is_warning}}  \n"
bash $
```

you could also unquote the text by adding `-qq` option:

```
bash $ <events.json jtc -w'[text]:<nStatus: Problem(.*)(?=Status: Problem)>R' -T'{{$1}}' -qq

Host:         {{name.name}} 
Host ID:    {{host.name}}
Host IP:     {{host.ip}}
{{/is_alert}}

{{#is_warning}}  
bash $
```

Thus the resulting query would be like this:

```
bash $ <events.json jtc -w'<title>l' -w'<^environment:>R' -w'<host>l' -w'<date_happened>l' -w'<^name:>R' -w'[text]:<Status: Problem(.*)(?=Status: Problem)>R' -T'{{$1}}'
"CPU Utilization Alert is ok on 50 over 50 host,names"
"environment:prod"
"i-0e4b192579a9b423b"
1573502725
"name:app2_backend-prod"
"\nHost:         {{name.name}} \nHost ID:    {{host.name}}\nHost IP:     {{host.ip}}\n{{/is_alert}}\n\n{{#is_warning}}  \n"
bash $
```